# How to check id in a string column in a SQL Server 2008 table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-express

I have a table that stores integer IDs of other table as comma separated string column. Now I want to find all rows in this table that have a specific ID in this string column.

Example

```
InwardHeader 
(
     inhdrid numeric(18, 0), 
     inwardno numeric(10, 0), 
     inwarddt datetime, 
     item numeric(10), 
     qty numeric(18, 2)
)

StockOutward 
(
    Stkouthdrid numeric(18, 0), 
    stkoutno numeric(18, 0), 
    stkoutdt datetime, 
    item numeric(10), 
    inwardids varchar(100)
)
```

The column `StockOutward.inwardids` contains comma separated values of multiple `InwardHeader.inhdrid`

I want to find rows from `stockoutward` which contain `inwardheader.inhdrid` for a specific value

Comment: You should provide the sample data and expected output all in the text format.

Comment: You should **NOT** store multiple values into a single column - this violates even the **first normal form** of proper database design, and makes it really hard and annoying to do any joins and just about anything else, too. Since you already **have** a relational database, you should use the **proper relational** means to model such 1:n relationships ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all is not good practice to store id on string field delimited by comma,
You should use 1:N relationships,
Anyway i prepared a solution for you(tested) like below:

```
SELECT [Stkouthdrid]
      ,[stkoutno]
      ,[stkoutdt]
      ,[item]
      ,[inwardids]
  FROM [test].[dbo].[StockOutward] 
  where  CHARINDEX((
  SELECT convert(varchar(10),[inhdrid])
  FROM [test].[dbo].[InwardHeader]
  where [inhdrid]=0), [inwardids]) > 0
```

Hope it Helps :)
[image]

Comment: It works atleast on my test data (very small )
will test it on real data after the corona lockdown is over

Comment: Perfect  wish you the bests!!